# Is there any difference between a Li-ion and a LiFePO4 BMS?

Tags: lithium-ion, bms, lithium-polymer

I am exploring how to make lithium battery packs and trying to build my own for electric vehicles.

I have learnt about both Li-ion and LiFePO4 cells and understood their differences.
My question is on the BMS (Battery Management System) used in lithium battery packs. I really got mixed information on whether the type of a BMS depends on the lithium cell type. These are mostly Chinese products which I am talking about, with no data Smsheet available.

Is there any difference between Li-ion BMSes and LiFePO4 BMSes? If there is no difference, then why are they sold separately? And if there is a difference, how can I test/verify which BMS is meant for which cell type?

Comment: Did you really understand their differences? Because they have different operating voltages. In my experience, LiFe is much rarer and if it was just labelled as a lithium BMS, I would assume it is not LiFe.

Comment: Lithium Ion and LiFePo4 use different voltages and charge regimens that a BMS has to account for. BMSes for these types of batteries are therefore not interchangeable. You could deduce the technology from some other part of the description i.e. a BMS for 3S, 11.1V is probably meant for LiIon cells (nominally 3.7V per cell) and a BMS for 4S, 12.8V is used for LiFePo4 (nominally 3.2V per cell).

Comment: If there is no data sheet available you should not be buying them!

Comment: All the voltage settings are different. Don't mix&match or use the wrong one.

Comment: @StarCat thanks for confirming that.

Comment: @DKNguyen I understood the differences of Li-ion and LiFePo4 cells and know that they have a different nominal voltages. But I was just wondering if the BMS can recognise and handle the cells as appropriate.

Comment: @user_1818839 Thanks for confirming that.

Comment: @RoyC In countries like India, electronic kits and components are mostly imported from China, they are absolutely cheap in price but has a drawback - often documentation/data sheets are not provided. Even if I want to I may not have enough option to procure one with a datasheet, hence I wanted to ask the experts here.

Comment: @sribasu No, it cannot tell the difference because there is an overlap in the operating voltage range. So if the cell reads something like 3.3V it can't know what kind of cell it is looking at.

Comment: @DKNguyen yes, that sounds logical too. The 2 ranges are not far apart, infact they overlap.